# HDInsight azure adls gen2 'InternalServerError' ARM Template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-hdinsight, azure-managed-identity, azure-data-lake-gen2

Creating Azure HDinsight Spark cluster with ADLS Gen 2,Userassigned managed idnetity with StorageBlobdataOwner role.
Successfully assigned msi role to storage but getting error with HDInsight deployment(Internal server error)
Theres some issue near HDInsight cluster(Storage profile)resource code  in the template i think. I could use some help here.Attached image below.

{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",

```
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "clusterType": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [ "hadoop", "hbase", "storm", "spark" ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The type of the HDInsight cluster to create."
        }
    },
    "clusterName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the HDInsight cluster to create."
        }
    },
    "clusterLoginUserName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "These credentials can be used to submit jobs to the cluster and to log into cluster dashboards."
        }
    },
    "clusterLoginPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "minLength": 10,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The clusterloginpassword must be at least 10 characters in length and must contain at least one digit, one upper case letter, one lower case letter, and one non-alphanumeric character except (single-quote, double-quote, backslash, right-bracket, full-stop). Also, the password must not contain 3 consecutive characters from the cluster username or SSH username."
        }
    },
    "sshUserName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "These credentials can be used to remotely access the cluster and should not be same as clusterLoginUserName."
        }
    },
    "sshPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "minLength": 6,
        "maxLength": 72,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "SSH password must be 6-72 characters long and must contain at least one digit, one upper case letter, and one lower case letter.  It must not contain any 3 consecutive characters from the cluster login name"
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
    },

    "HeadNodeVirtualMachineSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_D12_v2",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Standard_A4_v2",
            "Standard_A8_v2",
            "Standard_D3_v2",
            "Standard_D4_v2",
            "Standard_D5_v2",
            "Standard_D12_v2",
            "Standard_D13_v2"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "This is the headnode Azure Virtual Machine size, and will affect the cost. If you don't know, just leave the default value."
        }
    },
    "WorkerNodeVirtualMachineSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_D13_v2",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Standard_A4_v2",
            "Standard_A8_v2",
            "Standard_D1_v2",
            "Standard_D2_v2",
            "Standard_D3_v2",
            "Standard_D4_v2",
            "Standard_D5_v2",
            "Standard_D12_v2",
            "Standard_D13_v2"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "This is the workerdnode Azure Virtual Machine size, and will affect the cost. If you don't know, just leave the default value."
        }
    },
    "clusterHeadNodeCount": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 2,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Number of worker nodes"
        }
    },
    "clusterWorkerNodeCount": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 4,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Number of worker nodes"
        }
    },
    "StorageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Storage Account"
        }
    },
    "StorageAccountType": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Standard_LRS",
            "Standard_GRS",
            "Standard_ZRS",
            "Standard_RA-GRS"

        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Type of the Storage Account"
        }
    },
    "filesystemname": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the container"
        }
    },
    "UserAssignedIdentityName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the User Assigned Identity"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {

    "managedIdentityId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', parameters('UserAssignedIdentityName'))]",
    "StorageApiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "msiApiVersion": "2018-11-30",
    "HDInsightApiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
    "StorageBlobDataOwner": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b7e6dc6d-f1e8-4753-8033-0f276bb0955b')]",
    "StorageBlobDataContributor": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')]"
},
"resources": [

    {
        "name": "[parameters('UserAssignedIdentityName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('msiApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('StorageApiVersion')]",
        "name": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",

        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('StorageAccountType')]"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
            "encryption": {
                "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
                "services": {
                    "blob": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "file": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "isHnsEnabled": true,
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true

        }

    },
    {

        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('StorageAccountName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid(subscription().subscriptionId))]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('StorageAccountName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities',parameters('UserAssignedIdentityName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('StorageBlobDataOwner')]",
            "principalId": "[reference(variables('managedIdentityId'),variables('msiApiVersion')).principalId]"
        }
    },


    {
        "apiVersion": "[variables('HDInsightApiVersion')]",
        "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('StorageAccountName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities',parameters('UserAssignedIdentityName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "clusterVersion": "4.0",
            "osType": "Linux",
            "tier": "standard",
            "clusterDefinition": {
                "kind": "[parameters('clusterType')]",
                "componentVersion": {
                    "Spark": "2.3"
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "gateway": {
                        "restAuthCredential.isEnabled": true,
                        "restAuthCredential.username": "[parameters('clusterLoginUserName')]",
                        "restAuthCredential.password": "[parameters('clusterLoginPassword')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "[variables('managedIdentityId')]": {}
                }
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "storageaccounts": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('StorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]",
                        "isDefault": true,
                        "fileSystem": "[parameters('filesystemname')]",
                        "resourceId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('StorageAccountName')),variables('StorageApiVersion'))]",
                        "msiResourceId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities',parameters('UserAssignedIdentityName')),variables('msiApiVersion'))]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "computeProfile": {
                "roles": [
                    {

                        "name": "headnode",
                        "minInstanceCount": 1,
                        "targetInstanceCount": "[parameters('clusterHeadNodeCount')]",
                        "hardwareProfile": {
                            "vmSize": "[parameters('HeadNodeVirtualMachineSize')]"
                        },
                        "osProfile": {
                            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                        "scriptActions": []
                    },
                    {

                        "name": "workernode",
                        "targetInstanceCount": "[parameters('clusterWorkerNodeCount')]",
                        "autoscale": {
                            "capacity": {
                                "minInstanceCount": 3,
                                "maxInstanceCount": 10
                            }
                        },
                        "hardwareProfile": {
                            "vmSize": "[parameters('WorkerNodeVirtualMachineSize')]"
                        },
                        "osProfile": {
                            "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                        "scriptActions": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }

],
"outputs": {
    "storage": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('StorageAccountName')))]"
    },
    "cluster": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters', parameters('clusterName')))]"
    }
}
```

}

[InternalServerError and Operation detail shows "Anerror has occured" and no other info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkXh3.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Ensure that your storage account has the user-assigned identity with `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role permissions, otherwise cluster creation will fail.

---

If you are using Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and receive the error `AmbariClusterCreationFailedErrorCode: "Internal server error occurred while processing the request. Please retry the request or contact support."`.

To resolve this issue, open the Azure portal, go to your Storage account, and under Access Control (IAM), ensure that the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or the `Storage Blob Data Owner role` has Assigned access to the User assigned managed identity for the subscription. See [Set up permissions for the managed identity on the Data Lake Storage Gen2 account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-storage-gen2#set-up-permissions-for-the-managed-identity-on-the-data-lake-storage-gen2-account) for detailed instructions.

> Make sure you have followed the necessary steps to configure a Data Lake Storage gen2 account.

**Reference:** [Use Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 with Azure HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-storage-gen2#set-up-permissions-for-the-managed-identity-on-the-data-lake-storage-gen2-account)

Comment: Hey Pradeep, This is the error in operation details.{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}. I am creating a spark cluster. The role has been assigned through my template.

Comment: Ensure that your storage account has the user-assigned identity with Storage Blob Data Contributor role permissions, otherwise cluster creation will fail.

Comment: This issue is not resolved yet. I have raised a microsoft ticket and will update here once i get a resolution. Whatever suggestions i got here were already present in the template.

Comment: Could you please share the support ticket number to track internally?

Comment: Solved this! Just add depends on  user managed identity in the role assignments resource